# How can I get a window seat when checking in with LATAM?

Tags: air-travel, seating, tam-airlines

I'm trying to check in with LATAM and it's only possible to choose several seats in the whole plane, none of which are by the window, even including premium ones.

Since I tried to check-in as soon as it was possible (3 days before the flight), I don't think they have all been selected by someone else.

Is it possible they are only available when checking in on the airport? Or is it more probable that they're available for some selected passengers / other fare classes?

[image: check-in]

Comment: Are you sure you can only select seats at checkin?

Comment: @andrewmh20 when buying the ticket, I didn't have an option to select the seat (but I bought through another website, I'm not sure how it is when buying through LATAM). When I logged in before check-in was available, I could only upgrade my seat to premium.

Comment: According to [Choose your favorite seats](https://www.latam.com/en_us/plan-book/choose-your-favorite-seats/frequent-questions/), "Depending on the fare conditions of your ticket, you will be able to choose a standard seat at no extra cost or we will select a seat for you at random." so there is at least some advance seat selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible to choose a window seat.  Quite likely they are actually all taken or, at least, assigned.  You could (and should) keep doing online checkins in case people change their minds; a seat might become available.

I suspect your lack of a seat reservation was caused by booking through a third-party site.  It might make sense to book your tickets directly with the airline.  Alternatively, when you use a third-party site you should get a PNR (reservation) code that you can use to go to the airline's site to reserve a seat later.